# Determine Gaussian integral without using erf(z)

Tags: integration, error-function, gaussian-integral, approximate-integration

How can I compute the well-known integral,
$$ I(t,\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \int_0^t e^{-\frac{(\tau - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} d\tau$$
without using the $erf(z)$ definition.

I am looking for a non-faster way to obtain $I(t,\mu,\sigma)$, because $erf(z)$ trends to diverge in an iterative process varying $t$. I tried to approximate $I(t,\mu,\sigma)$ using the Gauss-Legendre quadrature, but results are not accurate enough.

Comment: "...$\mathrm{erf}(z)$ tends to diverge..." - that's not right, unless you mean that the implementation of the function in your computer is doing something weird. Gaussian quadrature is not competitive here unless you have enough nodes and weights. There are threads here on how to efficiently compute the error function; search around.

Comment: This is *by definition* a simple expression in $\operatorname{erf}$

Comment: You are, of course, correct, @HagenvonEitzen, that $erf$ is defined by the integral. I think in this case, however, that the OP means "computer implementation" when he says "definition."

Comment: You all are right, I mean "computer implementation". I have the theoretical solution but it does not work well...

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is to let $z = (\tau - \mu)/\sigma$, then, after the appropriate substitution, you get the well known Gaussian Integral.

Comment: I did it too, I really appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

In the [Wikipedia article on the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) there is a reference to a numerical solver implemented in the [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) computer algebra system using [Tanh-sinh quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature). The Wikipedia article on this algorithm states: 'Bailey (2006) found that: "The tanh-sinh quadrature scheme is the fastest known high-precision quadrature scheme, especially when the time for computing abscissas and weights is considered. It has been successfully employed for quadrature calculations of up to 20,000-digit precision. It works well for functions with blow-up singularities or infinite derivatives at endpoints."'

Comment: I employed a mathematical merge of some expressions (a simple exponential function and the Gaussian function) before integrate it. Hence, I avoided the annoying numerical divergence produced from the faster tendency of error function to zero and the simple exponential to infinite.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing your solution and numerical results.

Comment: I am so anger to show you the very last result of that